# calculating sum of all against all columns with matching row count

Tags: r

I have a df with several columns having values 0 or 1. Something like:

```
a b c d e
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

I would like to create a 5 by 5 matrix showing total count if columns have 1 in same row. I only want to consider 1's and in case of diagonal it would automatically reflect total row in that column with 1. Output something like:

```
  a b c d e
a 2 0 1 0 1
b 0 2 0 2 0
c 1 0 1 0 1 
d 0 2 0 2 0
e 1 0 1 0 1
```

Thanks.

Sudhir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to matrix and take cross product:

```
m <- as.matrix(d)
crossprod(m,m)
```

Comment: Thanks Marat...that is awesome.. didn't know that it would be so simple :)